# Cassandra insert boolean error

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am using Cassandra, and the vision info is like this:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

I found that in `CQL`, boolean can be inserted. [cql insert](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0)

My table schema is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.crew (
name text PRIMARY KEY,
alliance_trouble boolean,
bunk int
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

And when I use `cql` to insert

```
insert into crew (alliance_trouble) values ('true');
```

It shows:

```
   code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (true) for "alliance_trouble" of type boolean"
```

What's the issue here? How to insert `boolean` type in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> insert into crew (alliance_trouble) values ('true');
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid STRING constant (true) for "alliance_trouble" of type boolean"
```

I see two problems here.  #1, you are inserting the value `true` as a string constant.  Get rid of the single quotes.  But even that doesn't totally fix this:

```
> insert into crew (alliance_trouble) values (true);
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part name"
```

You cannot `INSERT` a value without also specifying a primary key, or `name` in this case:

```
> insert into crew (name,alliance_trouble) values ('Malcolm Reynolds',true);
> SELECT * FROM crew;
 name             | alliance_trouble | bunk
------------------+------------------+------
 Malcolm Reynolds |             True | null

(1 rows)
```

Comment: Just realize that, I am just curious, why the `datastax` gives the wrong information...

Comment: @Liquid the article you referenced was a blog post from 2012 about C* 1.1.  I have left a comment at the bottom indicating that boolean values should not be quoted.